# Посчитать кол-во элементов в списке внутри словаря

Tags: python, словари

На входе есть словарь:

```
{'response': [
{'uid': 1296468, 'first_name': 'Aleksandr', 'last_name': 'Kasatkin', 'last_seen': {'time': 1522334419, 'platform': 3}, 'online': 0, 'user_id': 1296468}, 
{'uid': 565862, 'first_name': 'Alexander', 'last_name': 'Osipenko', 'last_seen': {'time': 1522919428, 'platform': 4}, 'online': 0, 'user_id': 565862}
]}
```

На выходе должно получиться:

```
num = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict = {'response': [
{'uid': 1296468, 'first_name': 'Aleksandr', 'last_name': 'Kasatkin', 'last_seen': {'time': 1522334419, 'platform': 3}, 'online': 0, 'user_id': 1296468}, 
{'uid': 565862, 'first_name': 'Alexander', 'last_name': 'Osipenko', 'last_seen': {'time': 1522919428, 'platform': 4}, 'online': 0, 'user_id': 565862}
]}

print len(dict['response'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c = {'response': [
    {'uid': 1296468, 'first_name': 'Aleksandr', 'last_name': 'Kasatkin', 'last_seen': 
        {'time': 1522334419, 'platform': 3}, 'online': 0, 'user_id': 1296468},
    {'uid': 565862, 'first_name': 'Alexander', 'last_name': 'Osipenko', 'last_seen': 
        {'time': 1522919428, 'platform': 4}, 'online': 0, 'user_id': 565862}
]}
print("num = {}".format(len(c["response"])))
```

Проверка

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">

c = {'response': [
    {'uid': 1296468, 'first_name': 'Aleksandr', 'last_name': 'Kasatkin', 'last_seen': 
        {'time': 1522334419, 'platform': 3}, 'online': 0, 'user_id': 1296468},
    {'uid': 565862, 'first_name': 'Alexander', 'last_name': 'Osipenko', 'last_seen': 
        {'time': 1522919428, 'platform': 4}, 'online': 0, 'user_id': 565862}
]}
print("num = {}".format(len(c["response"])))
</script>
</body>
```

Вывод

```
num = 2
```